# Помогите разобраться с авторизацией на python api

Tags: python, api, python-2.x, request, auth

https://support.huawei.com/view/contentview/getFileStream?mid=SUPE_DOC&viewNid=EDOC1000126989&nid=EDOC1000126989&partNo=j005&type=htm#ainterface-for-access-authentication вот тут как авторизоваться на СХД, это все проходит, json возвращает значения.

Имеем код:

```
import http
import requests
import json
import ssl
import time
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

data = {
    "username": "storage",
    "password": "!123",
    "scope": "1"
  }

url = 'https://192.168.10.10:8088/deviceManager/rest/xxxxx/sessions'

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), verify=False)
token = json.loads(r.text)['data']['iBaseToken']
headers = { 'iBaseToken:' + token }
re = requests.get('https://192.168.10.10:8088/deviceManager/rest/2102350BVD10HA000036/performace_statistic/cur_statistic_data?CMO_STATISTIC_UUID=207:0A&CMO_STATISTIC_DATA_ID_LIST=26&timeConversion=0',  verify=False)
j = json.loads(re.text)
print j
```

Ну и соответственно получаю ошибку что не авторизован, postman если делаю запрос после авторизации то в cookie вижу сессию , как мне тут включать этот запрос в эту сессию

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы cookie, который вернул предыдущий запрос, использовался в следующих запросах используйте [механизм сессий](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) в requests.

Вместо `requests.post` делайте:

```
s = requests.Session()

# если здесь сервер возвращает cookie
s.post(...) 

# то здесь cookie будет автоматически использовано
# при условии, что запрос на тот же домен (или поддомен в зависимости от настроек куки)
s.get(...)
```

Если же передача нужна таки через `header`, то правильно так:

```
headers = {'iBaseToken': token }
```

Comment: Что то не работает так тоже, опять не подцепляет сессию, если через курл делать запрос то вот так работает, там возращается вот такое значение: curl --location --request GET 'https://192.168.10.10:8088/deviceManager/rest/2ssd2sadasdddddd/performace_statistic/cur_statistic_data?CMO_STATISTIC_UUID=207:0A&CMO_STATISTIC_DATA_ID_LIST=26&timeConversion=0' \
--header 'Cookie: session=ismsession=9461039656865404105162540432012254905313912205182898922992' , то есть как то надо хедерс в таком виде что ли подставить, то что от запроса post вернется токен

Comment: Возможно. Кстати, неправильно передаете header, добавил это в ответ.

Comment: Мне надо вот так по идеи, только как мне автоматом подгружать cookie из запроса post я не понимаю import requests

url = "https://192.168.10.10:8088/deviceManager/rest/036/performace_statistic/cur_statistic_data?CMO_STATISTIC_UUID=207:0A&CMO_STATISTIC_DATA_ID_LIST=26&timeConversion=0"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Cookie': 'session=ismsession=5456650095155832317338898984119337710216784589033404727258'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))

Comment: Если вручную добавляете и работает, а через `requests.Session` нет - то что-то делаете не так. Добавьте код с `requests.Session` в вопрос.

Comment: Передача идет через header

Comment: Это вы к чему? cookies всегда передаются через headers. Sessions в requests это механизм, который среди прочего передает сохраненные куки автоматически.

Answer (score -1):

Сильно не углублялся в суть вопроса, но мне кажется в Вашем запросе

```
re = requests.get('https://192.168.10.10:8088/deviceManager/rest/2102350BVD10HA000036/performace_statistic/cur_statistic_data?CMO_STATISTIC_UUID=207:0A&CMO_STATISTIC_DATA_ID_LIST=26&timeConversion=0',  verify=False)
```

не хватает headers, который Вы определили строчкой выше.

```
headers = { 'iBaseToken:' + token }

re = requests.get('https://192.168.10.10:8088/deviceManager/rest/2102350BVD10HA000036/performace_statistic/cur_statistic_data?CMO_STATISTIC_UUID=207:0A&CMO_STATISTIC_DATA_ID_LIST=26&timeConversion=0', headers={'iBaseToken: ' + token}  verify=False)
```

Comment: Тогда имеем такую ошибку: 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 31
, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 44
, in prepare_headers
    for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Да и вообще там сессию наверное надо передавать, после авторизации POSTом